# Bootstrap panels not stacking properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Web UI with a collection of bootstrap panels. Each panel has a different (variable) size and the panels are draggable. All panels are in the same row, to let bootstrap take care of the stacking.

This works fine for the second column as shown below:

[image]

However if stacking has to occur in the first column, bootstrap will always align with a panel in the second column, leading to this:

[image]

Where I would like Panel 3 to stack right underneath Panel 1. Is this even possible with panels or should I look into a different construct? Please note that I want to keep them in the same row, as dragging them around will change their order.

This is the html (see also http://www.bootply.com/yETTVnn4Yf#) :

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0">
  <div style="overflow: auto" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            TITLE 2
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            TITLE 1
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            TITLE 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            TITLE 3
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            TITLE 4
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need something like http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or http://masonry.desandro.com/